# What makes a webpage's sound continue after the page is closed?

Tags: ipad, safari, google-chrome, web-browser

Some websites that have sound/music keep the sound running even after the web browser is closed on iPad. Some other websites stop the sound when the page is closed. I suppose there must be some coding within the HTML to control this. How is this done?

Comment: Do you have any example?

Comment: For example, coffitivity.com keeps playing the sound after closing the browser, but youtube.com stops playing if I close the browser while it is playing.

Comment: I've been testing it but it does not happen to me. Do you actually **close** the web browser or just put it into background? Does it happen with both safari and chrome?

Comment: @Thecafremo Sorry if my description was not accurate. I am putting it to the background. It is the same with safari and chrome.

Comment: I recently upgrade my iPad mini to iOS 8.1 and started having this issue with YouTube videos. After closing the browser (with video still running) the audio continues for several seconds. This problem did not exist before upgrade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you may see, websites that keep the music running appear as the music app (here on iOS 6)

[image]

It uses the HTML5 audio feature. In the website you gave ([coffitivity.com](http://coffitivity.com)). They use the [JPlayer](http://jplayer.org/) plugin for jquery to use the HTML5 audio API.

Comment: So if the audio comes from HTML5 audio, it keeps playing, and if it is done by something else (e.g., flash), then it stops?

Comment: Since flash doesn't run on iOS you won't have any sound ;)

Comment: Right. Then what is the difference between youtube (run on the web browser, not the app)?

Comment: The same thing happens to YouTube. But notice that sometimes Safari opens the YouTube app. And the YouTube app doesn't become the "Music app".

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to stop on my iPad Air by going to Settings->General->Multitasking and turning off Persistent Video Overlay. (I did leave multitasking turned on.)

Answer (score 0):

The same seems to happening under Safari Version 7.0.1 (9537.73.11) and MacOSX 10.9.1.
A youtube video is watched and then a new web site is opened by typing a new address into the address bar. The new web site is loading but the youtube video sound still continues. closing the window and opening a new window "resolves" this.

Answer (score 0):

It plays out of cache when it is started. Whatever page you're on will attempt to download the entire audio and video in order to give the user a higher quality playback. There's an issue in the latest Facebook on iPhone where the audio keeps playing even after leaving the post. Depending on how much cache memory was used the audio will just keep on playing. For Facebook they blindly added the caching feature and didn't bother flushing it or killing the related process. It's called lazy development and poor QA result decisions. Releasing the rest of the updates was more important than fixing the symptom.

For the posts about minimizing the window I can only say LOL.... Good god. The active pages don't stop just because you minimized the window or opened a new tab while leaving the original open.